# Restore a 1:1 conversation in Skype Web SDK

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

Is it possible to restore a 1:1 conversation?

The `Conversation` object in the Skype SDK seems to have such functionality. You should be able to restore a conversation by passing a href to it. But when I pass a href string as parameter to `createConversation` it throws the following error:

`Error: ResourceNotFound
    at Error (native)
    at Exception (http://.../SkypeSDK.js:3346:31)
    at UCWA.get (http://.../SkypeSDK.js:15141:31)
    at init (http://.../SkypeSDK.js:40672:50)
    at new Conversation (http://.../SkypeSDK.js:41826:25)
    at createConversationModel (http://.../SkypeSDK.js:41963:36)
    at BaseModel.createConversation (http://.../SkypeSDK.js:42037:48)`

The lines can be a little bit off. I modified the `createConveration` method to pass the href to `Conversation`.
The href string has this format:

`/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/xxxxxxxxxxxx/communication/conversations/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`

We have the following situation:
One site has the normal SDK and waits for incoming calls. If you accept the call you should be redirected to a site with the SDK+CC and answer the call. Now we are stuck at how to pass the call. We also tried with it `getConversation`, but it doesn't return the last incoming conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you accept a call on one endpoint you can transfer it to another endpoint. However you cannot accept a call and then re-answer it on a different endpoint. Also, answering the call starts the process of connecting media so that endpoint has effectively picked up the call.
The href of each conversation is unique per application, and in your scenario you will have one for each site. These cannot be shared between applications.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. But how do I transfer it to another endpoint ?

Comment: Refer to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/ptaudiocalltransfer)